# How to get an array of objects from form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, form-for

Let's say I have **Workout** model that has many **Item**. Also **Workout** accepts nested attributes for **Items**. Using form_for I want to send parameters of **item** inside an array in the following manner:

```
"workout"=>{"workout_title"=>"title",
  "items"=>{
    ["name"=>"first item", "name"=>"second item"]
  }
 }
```

But for some reason I was only able to get it like this

```
 "workout"=>{"workout_title"=>"title",
   "items"=>{"name"=>"second_item"}
 }
```

How can I solve this?

Here's the form that produces the above parameters.

```
= form_for :workout, url: welcome_index_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.text_field :workout_title
  = f.fields_for :items, child_index: 1 do |builder|
    = builder.text_field :name
  = f.fields_for :items, child_index: 2 do |builder|
    = builder.text_field :name, id: 'workout_items_name_2', name: 'workout[items][name]'
  = f.submit 'Go'
```

Comment: You are not putting `name: 'workout[items][name]'` in the first `builder.text_field`

Comment: @PetrGazarov in this case only second parameter is being sent as well.

Comment: Remove the `name: 'workout[items][name]'` and in strong params give it `name[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let the `fields_for` generate all the items for you?

```
= form_for @workout, url: welcome_index_path, method: :post do |f|
  = f.text_field :title
  = f.fields_for :items do |builder|
    = builder.text_field :name
  = f.submit 'Go'
```

It would display text fields for all your items in `@workout`. Also, you would receive items in `params[:workout][:item_attributes]`. Plus, Rails' `@post.save(params[:workout])` would also create related items as well.

Comment: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "items" does not exist. This error happens when I changed :workout to @workout

Comment: The error says you don't have "items" table. In your question, you mentioned you have. Run migrations, I guess.

Comment: In this case I only have the sole input which sends over "workout"=>{"workout_title"=>"title"}

Comment: Do you see your items in the edit form? In your controller,  are you filtering your `params` (`params.require(:workout).permit(:name)`)?

Comment: Hmm... that's strange. Can you show us the rendered form HTML?